# In VS2010 Unit testing, can I detect if the test is being ran or debugged?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am using VS2010 unit testing framework. 
Next to testing my code I am also doing some timing things. However, this means that when I use debug mode to step through the test code, the timings are skewed. Can I detect in the code if the test is ran with "Run" or "Debug"?

Comment: have you tried, Debugger.IsAttached?

Comment: No. But indeed, that fixes my problem. Thanks for the fast answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe  `Debugger.IsAttached` will get you what you need